# Why does this facebook code no longer work but glues my page together?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, facebook

I was using some facebook code to display a like button on my page. I have it in my _SiteLayout.cshtml page. At first it worked just dandy; and I've got the same exact code working on this site: www.bigsurgarrapata.com

But now I'm using the LinkShare Webhelper to display a bunch of different social networking icons, and don't need the standalone facebook code for my current site. Besides, it for some reason stopped working anyway. However, if I remove it, the structure of my pages that reference _SiteLayout.cshtml goes all to Dallas (or Cleveland, YMMV). Here it is in context (between the head and the body):

```
    </head>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<body>
```

Why would removing this alter my page's contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that was between the head and body, it was in an invalid location.  It manipulates the structure of the document (fjs.parentNode.insertBefore), possibly in an invalid way because of its location.  The effects of that may vary in different browsers and do unexpected things.  Browsers may try to compensate for the broken code or trigger something like quirks mode, using different rules for processing the content. If there was something compensating for the invalid code that made it look right, then when you remove the invalid code, whatever had been making it look right may now make it look wrong.

Comment: I must have some malformed html above or below that block of code; I'm sure enough of it that I'm marking this as the answer (but I won't know until tonight or maybe even tomorrow morning).

Comment: Yes, it was a matter of adding a missing right-angle bracket to a script tag. I can finally escort fb out the door without the roof collapsing.

Answer (score 1):

//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1 -  This is the link in your JS.

It does show you javascript, so it seems that it's running from there.

Answer (score 1):

On the bigsurgarrapata page, you have it after the opening body tag, which is what facebook recommends:

> "Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the
>   opening  tag."

-via http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Here, you've put it between `</head>` and `<body>`. Maybe try moving it into the `<body>` element?

Comment: But the problem is, when it's *gone* it's causing problems.